# Get the value from a nested dictionary.Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to get a list of the values from a nested dictionary.

```
d = {2.5: {2005: 0.3}, 2.6: {2005: 0.4}, 5.5: {2010: 0.8}, 7.5: {2010: 0.95}}

def get_values_from_nested_dict(dic):
    list_of_values = dic.values()
    l = []
    for i in list_of_values:
        a = i.values()
        l.append(a)
    return l

d1 = get_values_from_nested_dict(d)
print(d1)
```

My results:

```
[dict_values([0.3]), dict_values([0.4]), dict_values([0.8]), dict_values([0.95])]
```

But I want the list to be:

```
[0.3,0.4,0.8,0.95]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate again through the values of the internal dictionary and append each of them to the output variable.

```py
def get_values_from_nested_dict(dic):
    l = []
    for outer_value in dic.values():
        for value in outer_value.values():
            l.append(value)
    return l
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use a double-comprehension (equivalent to a nested loop) on the `dict`s's values:

```py
d = {2.5: {2005: 0.3}, 2.6: {2005: 0.4}, 5.5: {2010: 0.8}, 7.5: {2010: 0.95}}


[y for x in d.values() for y in x.values()]
# [0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.95]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I didnt know how to use dict comprehension.

Comment: @JohnTipotas [MrJuicyBacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58634941/5218354) is the equivalent looping without using comprehension. Note that this is not considered a `dict` comprehension, but rather a `list` comprehension, since the resulting object is a `list`. `dict` comprehension also exist but they have a slightly different syntax and, most importantly they produce a `dict` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
In [97]: d                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[97]: {2.5: {2005: 0.3}, 2.6: {2005: 0.4}, 5.5: {2010: 0.8}, 7.5: {2010: 0.95}}

In [98]: list(map(lambda x:list(x.values())[0], d.values()))                                                                                                                                                
Out[98]: [0.3, 0.4, 0.8, 0.95]
```